# jQuery UI dropdown select

Tags: jquery-ui

I wanna have a dropdown menu like this link: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html
(The one that are right below "Live example" line);
I haven't got many experience of working with jQuery UI, and I guess that result is produced by using it. Could you suggest me a way to create that dropdown.
Thank you.
P/S: that may be ok if it is not using jQuery UI (it's just my guess)

Answer (score 0):

That solution doesn't appear too complex - they've got all the data already, and they're just hiding rows depending on what's selected.

On the other hand, as that's an open source project, you could just [download it](http://datatables.net/download/) or use the [hosted versions](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_DataTables_Releases_on_the_CDN_6) and integrate it on your site, which is probably easier than rolling your own solution.

Comment: Let me explain again. I just need to create that drop down to have a similar appearance like the like I referenced to. I used firebug to se the css style for it, but it seems like it doesn't apply any special style (that's really odd).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. This is just default style in Firefox (There's no style applying for it yet). I got this misunderstand due to changing browser.